# RoR and Postgresql DB: belongs_to association works, but not has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, webpack-dev-server

I have two Models,

`class Store < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'storeid'
  has_many : employees
end`

`class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store, optional: true, foreign_key: :storeid
end`

With the Following schema.rb,

```
  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "storeid", null: false
    t.index ["store_id"], name: "index_employees_on_store_id"
  end

  create_table "stores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "storeid", null: false
    t.index ["storeid"], name: "index_stores_on_storeid", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "employees", "stores", column: "store_id"
  add_foreign_key "employees", "stores", column: "storeid", primary_key: "storeid"
end
```

My issue is that when I go to rails console, and try to query `Store.first.employees`, I just get a reference to the model and then it crashes. When I do `Employee.first.stores` It returns the appropriate associated store to the employee.

p.s. I'm aware of the, Rails naming convention issues

---

**EDIT 0:**
This is my latest migration

```
class Keys < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    add_index :stores, [:storeid], :unique => true
    add_reference :employees, :stores, foreign_key: true
    add_foreign_key :employees, :stores, column: :storeid, primary_key: :"storeid"
  end

  def down
    execute "ALTER TABLE stores DROP CONSTRAINT table_pkey;"
  end
end
```

Tables Migration:

```
class Stores < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :stores do |t|
      t.column :storeid, :text, null: false, unique: true
      t.column :contactname, :text, null: true
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Employees < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :employees do |t|
      t.column :storeid, :text, null: false, unique: true
      t.column :name, :text, null: true
    end
  end
end
```

---

Comment: Can you please provide your migration to create the models?

Comment: I assume this is a typographical error since it's a syntax problem: `has_many : employees`. Try using `has_many :employees, foreign_key: :storeid` in the `Store` model.

Comment: @lurker I was not careful when copy/pasting. it should be `has_many :employees,`

Comment: @lurker It seems to work once I modify this line: `has_many :employees, foreign_key: :storeid`. I will mark this as solved. Thank you!

Comment: That's great! If you find my posted answer acceptable, then perhaps you could check it as "accepted". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `Store` model is missing the foreign key:

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'storeid'
  has_many :employees, foreign_key: :storeid
end
```